# MLCP database to database copy. Collection names coming through with and without quotes

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

The source database has 6 unquoted collection names after an mlcp db-to-db copy the target database has replica collection names quoted and unquoted versions. When I restore the source db's backup onto the target db the latter has only the expected 6 unquoted collection names. The target database is cleared prior to the mlcp task and checked as empty before starting the mlcp run. The script I used seems fairly unremarkable:

```
bash mlcp.sh copy -mode local -input_host localhost -input_port 8000 
-input_database <source-db> -input_username admin -input_password admin 
-output_host <target-svr> -output_port 8000 -output_database <target-db> 
-output_username <target-uname> -output_password <target-pwd> 
--thread_count 4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean with quoted and unquoted collections? Also the first sentence seems to be missing some interpunction, making it a bit confusing what you mean..

Comment: This is the xquery to list collections

    for $collection in cts:collections() return xdmp:estimate( fn:collection($collection) ) || " - " || $collection . 

These samples of the counts and collection names
    Source database
    17281 - expanded-datasheet     

    Target database
    19401 - "expanded-datasheet"
      9879 - expanded-datasheet

Comment: Apologies for another rush job. I meant to say:  I used cts:collections() to list the collections and these are sample values from the source dbase (expanded-datasheet) and Target dbase ("expanded-datasheet" & expanded-datasheet).

Comment: That sounds like a bug in MLCP. Which versions of ML and MLCP are you using?

Comment: ML is 8.0-4.2 and MLCP is mlcp-1.3-3

Comment: Could you run a test with latest MLCP (8.0-5)? http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp

Comment: I've restarted the transfer using MLCP 8-0.5 and so far it things are looking as they should so it looks like you were correct grtjn about there being a bug in the older version of MLCP.

Comment: While the older version of MLCP loaded records incorrectly the new version of MLCP (8-0.5) generates XDMP-EXTIME errors and WARN contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter messages.

Comment: Feel free to open a new StackOverflow question, MarkLogic support ticket, or github issue for mlcp https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump .  Make sure to provide mvce http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can fight EXTIME timeouts by reducing thread_count, transaction_size, and/or batch_size. I'd first try transaction_size 1, there might be a few large files in there. For the bug I'd recommend following Sam's advice to file a ticket..

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'll follow up as suggested.